# Retrieve firebase data in the same order as its added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I retrieve the firebase list in the same order as it is added.
Looks like I’m getting them in a random order. I need to have them in order to draw my polyline in correct order.

```
List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot direction : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (direction.getKey().equals(firebaseKey)) {
                MyLatLng wantedDirection = direction.getValue(MyLatLng.class);
                for (Waypoints waypoint : wantedDirection.getWaypoints().values()) {
                    double lat = waypoint.getLatitude();
                    double lang = waypoint.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lang);
                    latLngList.add(latLng);
             }
```

I want the JSON file to be in the same order as it the entries were added to the firebase list:

```
{
  "timeStamp" : "2016-05-03 23:06:05",
  "waypoints" : {
    "-KGsf4xB_rZbsAMW4I2D" : {
      "latitude" : 58.338713,
      "longitude" : 11.90885
    },
    "-KGsf5M9YtZn6Yq22Kts" : {
      "latitude" : 58.339218,
      "longitude" : 11.910351
    },
    "-KGsf5qSV3X7cAIBtANF" : {
      "latitude" : 58.340572,
      "longitude" : 11.915417
    },
    "-KGsf6oww79POAY_e7kf" : {
      "latitude" : 58.342271,
      "longitude" : 11.921562
    },
    "-KGsf7JBaac5o7VMEZMh" : {
      "latitude" : 58.344006,
      "longitude" : 11.926909
    },
    "-KGsf7nGpMEgPA0j1rRl" : {
      "latitude" : 58.345594,
      "longitude" : 11.929302
    },
    "-KGsf8HjFtn7Dxpx-DpO" : {
      "latitude" : 58.347846,
      "longitude" : 11.931577
    },
    "-KGsf8ltvEBeqXE_me8Z" : {
      "latitude" : 58.350397,
      "longitude" : 11.932334
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend storing a timestamp with each waypoint or store an order key like mentioned by Nik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataSnapshot.getChildren()` will return the children in the order in which you've queried them from the database. If you're not specifying `orderByChild()` or `orderByPriority()` explicitly, that order will be by key, which means they will be iterated in the order they were inserted.

But for the waypoints, you are defining your own order:

```
for (Waypoints waypoint : wantedDirection.getWaypoints().values()
```

The `values()` of a `Map` are not going to be in a specific order afaik.

### Update

To see the order in which the items are retrieved from Firebase, you can traverse the `DataSnapshot`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot direction: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    DataSnapshot waypoints = direction.child("waypoints");
    for (Waypoints waypoint: waypoints.getChildren()) {
        double lat = waypoint.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double lon = waypoint.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, long);
        latLngList.add(latLng);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can look for a map that returns its entries in the order of its keys.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Waypoints> waypoint : wantedDirection.getWaypoints().entrySet()) {
                        String key = waypoint.getKey();
                        Waypoints value = waypoint.getValue();

                        double lat = value.getLatitude();
                        double lang = value.getLongitude();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lang);
                        latLngRealList.add(latLng);
                    }
```